# How do I publish to a private nuget repository from the command line?

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I've found [several](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference) [helpful](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package) [documents](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/package/use/publish) on this topic but I can't seem to make head nor tail of them. Can someone explain to me like I'm five how I can publish to a private nuget repository from the command line? Specifically, how do I authenticate to my artifactory nuget repository? The command I'm using is

`nuget push Mypkg1.0.0.nupkg -Source http://artifactory/artifactory/api/nuget/MypgkRepo`

I have zero experience with nuget but am working on making it part of our build process in order to build only what changed and fetch the rest from the repo. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the trick is you have to add an authenticated source before trying to push. For example,

```
nuget sources add -Name A -Source http://af/artifactory/api/nuget/MyPkgRepo -User user -pass pass
```

[(from here)](https://gist.github.com/xavierdecoster/3205826)

Then call `setapikey` like this

```
nuget setapikey user:pass -Source A
```

[Source](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/NuGet+Repositories#NuGetRepositories-NuGetAPIKeyAuthentication)

After doing that, I can say

```
nuget push Mypkg1.0.0.nupkg -Source A
```

and it says "Using credentials from config" rather than asking me for mine.